# R - Logical operator in subset() is a string

Tags: r, subset

I feel I have a simple question, but I cannot get my code to work. In short, I want the condition statement in a subset() function to be a string. This mostly works, except for the logical operator. So I would want something like this;

```
my.string = "gender == female"
```

Subsequently I would run;

```
myData = subset(myData, my.string)
```

I have tried things like;

```
myData = subset(myData, parse(text = my.string))
myData = subset(myData, eval(parse(text = my.string)))
```

But of no avail. The main reason I want to do this, is because I want you to be able to make filter conditions up front in the code, so this would be;

```
filter.variable[[1]] = "gender"
filter.condition[[1]] = "==" # or %in%
filer.value[[1]] = "female"
i = 1
my.string = paste(filter.variable[[i]],filter.condition[[i]],filter.value[[i]])
```

This way I do not have to hardwire any filters in R.
Any suggestions are much appreciated,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to have quotes around 'female' i.e. This can be easily done in `dQuote`

```
my.string <- paste0('gender == ', dQuote('female', FALSE))
```

Or can do this with `"` wrapped

```
my.string = 'gender== "female"'
```

and then use that in `subset` with `eval(parse`

---

Using a reproducible example

```
my.string <- paste0('Species == ', dQuote('setosa', FALSE))
subset(iris, eval(parse(text = my.string)))
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# ...
```

Comment: You can also have `my.string = "Sample_Type == 'A'"`, 
`subset(df, eval(parse(text=my.string)))`

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually worked. I never used the dQuote before, so learned something new.